# use EMR to copy dynamoDB tables across different accounts

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-emr, emr

I have many tables of information in one DynamoDB account that I would like to transfer to another account. I see that you can copy tables within one account using EMR like so: http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/EMRforDynamoDB.html, but is there a way to transfer across different accounts?

Answer (score 2):

Just download the S3 export and upload it to a bucket on the new account then you can use dynamodb import.

Comment: Attention, this requires that PITR is enabled, PITR has an additional cost per GB month, but it cannot be paid per day or hour, if you enable it for just a minute and disable it you will pay the same as you had enabled for a whole month.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this for Dynamo (but works for S3). You can read the cross-account IAM details here :

Cross-Account API Access Using IAM Roles - AWS Identity and Access Management : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/cross-acct-access.html